# Print Current Time In Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have written some code in python for a live time in tkinter.
Whenever I run the code it comes up with some numbers on the tkinter window like `14342816time`. Is there a way to fix this?

```
import tkinter
import datetime

window = tkinter.Tk()

def time():
    datetime.datetime.now().time()
    datetime.time(17, 3,)
    print(datetime.datetime.now().time())


tkinter.Label(window, text = time).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you are missing the parenthesis from your `tkinter.Label(window, text=time()).pack()` --> notice text=time`()`

Answer (score 0):

After some fixes to your code, I came up with the following, which should at least get you started toward what you want:

```
import datetime
import tkinter

def get_time():
    return datetime.datetime.now().time()


root = tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.Label(root, text = get_time()).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The imports are needed so that your program knows about the contents of the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) modules - you may be importing them already, however, I can't tell that for certain from what you posted. You need to create a window into which you put your label, which wasn't happening; following convention, I called that parent (and only) window "root". Then I put the Label into root. I changed the name of your `time()` function to `get_time()`, since it's best to avoid confusing fellow programmers (and maybe yourself) with a function that shares its name with another (the [`time()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) in [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time)). I removed two lines in `get_time()` that don't actually accomplish anything. Finally, I changed the print you had to a return, so that the value can be used by the code calling the function.

There are other improvements possible here. If you're content with the time as it is, you could eliminate the get_time function and just use [datetime.datetime.now()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now).[time()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) instead of calling `get_time()`. However, I suspect you might want to do something to clean up that time before it is displayed, so I left it there. You might want to research the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) modules some more, to see how to clean things up.

Comment: @mltechi: I appreciate your effort to help. However, if you're going to edit a post, please make actual improvements (making random text a blockquote isn't an improvement) and be consistent (e.g. either code highlight only the first occurrence of a module or function name and provide a link, highlight every occurrence, or highlight none - highlighting randomly is annoying).